# How to skip insertion of a duplicate record and continue in Sybase T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I am inserting several million rows using the following simple `insert` clause:

```
insert into DEST_TABLE
select *
from SRC_TABLE
```

However, there may be duplicates while inserting, which will throw an error and the entire operation will end.

Is there a way to perform the insertion operation from start to finish and not break from duplicate insertion errors aka. ignore duplicate insertion errors and do not insert them?

Answer (score 2):

Best to avoid the issue all together and filter them out beforehand:

```
insert into DEST_TABLE
select *
from SRC_TABLE
EXCEPT
select *
from DEST_TABLE
```

Comment: This is good.  Does it help when duplicate records from the current INSERT exist?  In other words, I can see where it prevents duplicates from rows that were already there, but what if my insert statement includes duplicates within itself?

Answer (score 1):

These are the way to handle duplicate rows.

1. remove the constraint and insert rows.
   then to remove duplicates  create clustered index on table with option ignore_dup_row
2. remove all  constraints  create clusetered index on table with option ignore_dup_row. it wouldn't insert if row is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the duplicates insertion error can only come from constraints in your `DEST_TABLE`.

So remove the constraints in DEST_TABLE, Insert, clean datas, and put constraints back.

Which might be problematic in some cases, if you already have datas in your `DEST_TABLE`.

The other (better) solution would be to take datas without duplicates, by changing your `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe where clause will be good?

```
insert into DEST_TABLE
select *
from SRC_TABLE S
where not exists
      (
         select 1
         from DEST_TABLE D
         where D.id=S.id
      )
```